# Not able to Select DateInterval with IntervalMemberQ

Tags: filtering, date-and-time

I can use Select to extract rows with specific dates from my dataset, but I'd like to instead select all rows that fall within a date interval.   From the documentation, it appears that IntervalMemberQ applied to DateInterval should work, but I've not had success:

Note that the syntax for IntervalMemberQ is reversed from MemberQ, and is thus IntervalMemberQ[di,#] rather than IntervalMemberQ[#,di].

```
dataset = {{DateObject[{2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}], "stuffA", 10, 
        100}, {DateObject[{2020, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}], "stuffB", 20, 
        200}, {DateObject[{2020, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0}], "stuffC", 30, 300}}; 

do1 = DateObject[{2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}]
do2 = DateObject[{2020, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}]
Select[dataset, MemberQ[#, do1] &]
Select[dataset, MemberQ[#, do2] &]
di = DateInterval[{do1, do2}]
Select[dataset, IntervalMemberQ[di,#] &]
```

[image]

Comment: try `di = DateInterval[First/@{do1, do2}];Select[dataset, IntervalMemberQ[di,First@#] &]`?

Comment: Thanks @klgr.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that need to be overcome.

The first is this:

MemberQ will return True if any of the elements in the row correspond to the specified date

```
MemberQ[dataset[[1]], do1]
```

> True

However, IntervalMemberQ evaluates all the elements in the row, and thus returns:

```
IntervalMemberQ[di, dataset[[1]]]
```

> {True, False, False, False}

Since the date values are in the first column, I need to select the first element of IntervalMemberQ's output:

```
IntervalMemberQ[di, dataset[[1]]]
```

> True

Thus the expected solution is:

```
Select[dataset, IntervalMemberQ[di, #][[1]] &]
```

However this reveals the second problem, which is that IntervalMemberQ drops the last date:

> [image]

To address this, it is necessary to specify an end date that is just beyond the desired end date:

```
do3 = DateObject[{2020, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0}]
di3 = DateInterval[{do1, do3}]
Select[dataset, IntervalMemberQ[di3, #][[1]] &]
```

> [image]

I.e., IntervalMemberQ selects dates such that:

interval start date <= date < interval end date